# Regex to replace 'string \t' with 'string |'

Tags: regex, gedit

I've this kind of file (a csv):

```
(\t = tab)

ID \t   Name \t Root Bridge \t  Count
0   \t default  \t gateway1 \t 2
```

In Gedit (using the 'regex' mark check), I need to replace tabs with `|` to make it a table compatible with the Docuwiki format.

I thought that because I've a recurrent pattern of `%string% \t` I could easily replace that with a regex that said `%string% |`.

But it looks like I'm missing something.

I tried with `s/[.*\t]/[.*|]/g` but it doesn't work.

I probably didn't understand something basic about how regex works.

Thanks in advance

PS: this is my first question on StackExchange and tried to follow the recommendations on "how to write a question". I hope I got it right.

Comment: If you replace a tab char with `|`, can you use a literal string replacement?

Comment: Try escaping the | character.

Comment: I don't know how special gedit is in this, but the square brackets are usually used to create a group of characters. What is `[.\t]`  supposed to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need regex, but if you want exactly the following:

replace 'string \t' with 'string |'

you can use this

```
s/([^\t]+)\t/\1 |/g
```

in gedit or notepad++ refers to the matched group are notified with \groupnumber, in othe rlanguage with $groupnumber.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `(\t|\|)`. Should working.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need regex for this. Just copy-paste a tab character and do a simple "search & replace", which works in any editor.